# C# Stringbuilder corrupting content when adding lots of text

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder, corruption

I've run into an issue with stringbuilder which I can't seem to solve. To simplify the problem I create the following method:

```
private static string TestBigStrings() {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 1; i < 1500; i++) {
    string line = "This is a line isn't too big but breaks when we add to many of it.";
    builder.AppendLine(line);
  }

  return builder.ToString();
}
```

It should just add that line 1500 times, and afterwards combine it to a string and return it. However instead of just combining it corrupts the content. Somewhere in the middle of the result you'll find the text:

```
This is a line isn't too big but breaks when we add to many of it. 
This is a line isn't too big but breaks when we add to many of it. 
This is a line isn't too big but breaks when we add to many of it. 
This is a line isn't too big but breaks when we add to many of ...s a line isn't too big but breaks when we add to many of it. 
This is a line isn't too big but breaks when we add to many of it. 
This is a line isn't too big but breaks when we add to many of it. 
This is a line isn't too big but breaks when we add to many of it.
```

The project is a simple Console. I've also tried all other solutions to check if this is possible some other way, like:

- Writing the text to file (same corruption and breaks off to early)
- Writing it to a memory stream and reading that (same corruption)
- Using a List and joining that (same corruption)
- Just using += on a string (same corruption)
- using string.concat (same corruption)

All my colleagues I asked are running into the same issue as well, so it should not be PC related. Does anybody have a clue what is happening here?

Comment: Can't reproduce it...Give us more info which version of .NET/VS/ x86/x64

Comment: @GeorgeVovos because it's impossible, specially happen on all his colleagues PC.

Comment: I also ran the code and the problem was not reproduced - .NET 4.5.

Comment: Please show the full code which writes the string to a file.

Comment: I had expected to see a fatal bug of .NET, but I was disappointed :(

Comment: The "..." happens when the *Text Visualizer* performs unexpected truncation, is that what your looking at the text in? [Connect bug & workaround](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2016177/text-visualizer-misses-corrupts-text-in-long-strings)

Comment: To be honest, I see the "broken" line when open the result with the Text Visualizer. However if I write it to a text file and open it with Notepad or similar, everything is just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you're experiencing?

[image: text visualizer]

Well, that's just the debugger *lying* to you. It will shorten strings which are too long to avoid excessive memory usage.

I wrote that string to a file, with a simple:

```
File.WriteAllText("BigString.txt", str);
```

And guess what: the string is in there as expected, and it's not corrupted in any way.

Comment: That's it! I was indeed using the debugger. Don't know I missed this since I actually tried writing to a file, but it seems to work. Thank you!